# Name of song in Episode 8 of No Game No Life at around 6:05

Tags: music, no-game-no-life

As title says, Looking for name of song at time stamp. It also plays again at 7:20

Answer (score 1):

The song you are looking for is Choisies, produced by SuperSweep. It's the 11th song in the OST list of the anime. [Here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_YMcOOEMSPY&list=PLTfki024aB5c6e_GMyr3yu0OoPnuu4Omv&index=11) the youtube link for the song and the rest of No Game No Life's OST.